# Solid Guage Chart with 2 data series in Highharts

Tags: highcharts, series

Does anyone if it's possible to create the following type of chart using Highcharts:

[image]

I was trying to use the Solid Guage type but couldn't find a way to incorporate a 2nd data series into the chart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a points in series and regular size and distance by innerRadius / outerRadius.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [{
            name: 'First car',
            radius: 100,
            innerRadius: 80,
            y: 80
        }, {
            name: 'Second car',
            radius: 80,
            innerRadius: 60,
            y: 120
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y:-10
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> km/h'
        }
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/94akab33/2/
Missing elements can by added by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is exactly what I needed. Appreciated. Quick question - anyway to create that outer border around the first data series (the line that joins the circle) ?

Comment: Use a [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer) to add a circle or use a [background](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.background) in pane and try to prepare stops.

Comment: Perfect. I used the renderer and was able to replicate.